# Installing RVM on mac os yosetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

We spent 2 days on that mistake:
When installing rvm:

```
rvm install 2.2.0 --autolibs=enable
```

If you receiving something like:

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install automake openssl',
```

(or whatever amount of requirements).

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
brew install automake
    brew install openssl
```

etc. Also we received some mistakes with rights of directory. Just change rights of directories that it says to you.